# df.loc astype(int) does not work & html_style adds even more decimals

Tags: python

This is my file, indexes are 'Dispose', 'Damage' and 'Ratio'
Basically, one already annoying thing is, that there are no decimals for Dispose and Damage in the CSV I am reading from to get this data..

```
>>> file
            WK-3    WK-2    WK-1  Week to Date
Dispose   150.00  150.00  150.00         200.0
Damage    100.00  100.00  100.00         100.0
Ratio       0.33    0.33    0.33           0.5
```

If I now try to get rid of the decimals, it does not work - the code below shows the expected results in my command prompt...

```
>>> file.loc['Dispose'].astype(int)
WK-3            150
WK-2            150
WK-1            150
Week to Date    200
Name: Dispose , dtype: int32
```

..but if I try to save it in my file, there's no difference.

```
>>> file.loc['Dispose'] = file.loc['Dispose'].astype(int)
>>> file
            WK-3    WK-2    WK-1  Week to Date
Dispose   150.00  150.00  150.00         200.0
Damage    100.00  100.00  100.00         100.0
Ratio       0.33    0.33    0.33           0.5
```

That's my problem #1.
Problem #2 is, I am using this data to create an email alert.

```
import pandas as pd
from win32com.client import Dispatch

outlook = Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'my email address'
mail.Subject = 'Dispose Damage Alert - TEST' 

def f(val):
   return ['color: darkred; background-color: salmon' if  x < 0.4  and x < 1 else 'color: darkgreen; background-color: lightgreen'  if x > 0.4 and x  < 1 else '' for x in val]

html_style = file.style.apply(f, axis = 1 )  
html_text = html_style.render() 

mail.HTMLBody = """
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>html title</title>
<style  type="text/css" >\n

body {
    background-color: #fffffff;
    font-family: Calibri, Myriad;
}

table th, table td {
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

</head>
<html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
""" + html_text +  """ 
</table>
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
""" 


mail.Send()
```

And the result shows even more decimals :(

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data types are defined per column in Pandas. When you overwrite the datatype for all elements in a row of the DataFrame, it doesn't stick, as the fields take their data type from the column.

A simple solution would be to transpose your table.

```
file = file.T
```

Then you can do the operations you intended (changing the data type), but on the [columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648923/463796), not the rows, e.g.:

```
file = file.astype({"Dispose": int})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! ok, so looks like there's no way to have the ratio at the end of the table, as this must be a float :/ what a pity ^^

Comment: Of course you can have series of floats, independent of the data type of the rest of the table (e.g. ints). But you should put the ratio as the last *column*, not the last *row*!